# Meteor queries not working with Meteor.Collection.ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm having a lot of trouble getting query results for certain collections in Meteor. 
I have set

```
idGeneration : 'MONGO'
```

in the collection definitions, and in the mongo shell these collections look like this :

```
the document i want, call it documentW (from CollectionA) = { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("7032d38d35306f4472844be1"), 
    "product_id" : ObjectId("4660a328bd55247e395edd23"), 
    "producer_id" :  ObjectId("a5ad120fa9e5ce31926112a7") }

documentX (from collection "Products") = {
    _id : ObjectId("4660a328bd55247e395edd23")
}

documentY (from collection "Producers") = {
    _id : ObjectId("a5ad120fa9e5ce31926112a7")
}
```

If i run a query like this in Meteor

```
CollectionA.findOne({ product_id : documentX._id, producer_id : documentY._id})
```

I'm expecting to get my documentW back... but I get nothing.

When I run this query in the mongo shell

```
db.collectiona.find({ product_id : ObjectId("4660a328bd55247e395edd23"), producer_id : 
ObjectId("a5ad120fa9e5ce31926112a7") })
```

I get my documentW back no problem.

Of course in Meteor if I call

```
console.log(documentX._id)
```

I get this

```
{ _str : "4660a328bd55247e395edd23" }
```

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here ? I have tried all kinds of things like

```
Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(documentX._id._str)
```

but the search still returns empty...

Running the latest 0.7.0.1 version of Meteor...

Comment: How are you retrieving `documentX` and `documentY`? I think EJSON should automatically convert the weird `{_str: value}` object to a `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` object.

Comment: Let's say documentX and documentY are in object form - e.g. as a result of documentX = Products.findOne() (where it's the only document in the collection) and documentY = Producers.findOne()...

Comment: I agree when I do a query, it seems from the code that Meteor should be turning the weird object to a mongo ObjectId...

Comment: Nevermind, that is an `ObjectID`. The `_str` property is just how Meteor models the `ObjectID` type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answers your question, but I can't put this code in a comment. This code is working for me, trying to follow what I believe you are trying to do:

```js
Products = new Meteor.Collection("products", {
  idGeneration: "MONGO"
});
Producers = new Meteor.Collection("producers", {
  idGeneration: "MONGO"
});
CollectionA = new Meteor.Collection("a", {
  idGeneration: "MONGO"
});

Products.insert({
  foo: "bar"
});
Producers.insert({
  fizz: "buzz"
});

var documentX = Products.findOne();
var documentY = Producers.findOne();

CollectionA.insert({
  product_id: documentX._id,
  producer_id: documentY._id
});

var documentW = CollectionA.findOne({
  product_id: documentX._id,
  producer_id: documentY._id
});

console.log(documentW); // This properly logs the newly created document
```

This is on 0.7.0.1. Do you see anything in your code that diverges from this?

Comment: i've just run this code in a sample app and it's not working... which means i should maybe re-install 0.7.0.1...

Comment: Yes, Meteor 0.7.0.1 on OSX Mavericks. It's a new app with just this one JS file, and the only thing in my HTML is `<body></body>`. Do you get anything at all in your console?

Comment: in any case +1 for your help and i'll get back when i've re-installed

Comment: No problem. I'd be interested to know what the issue is if you figure it out. A `meteor update`, `meteor reset` never hurts anything. http://i.imgur.com/qDJIIRf.png